# In django admin make object and refer from other object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I don't know if it's even possible but i hope you can help me. These are my models:

```
class Aufgaben(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('name'), null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)


class Zusatzinfo(models.Model):
    info = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('info'), null=False, blank=False, max_length=1000)


class Person(models.Model):
#more fields
    aufgaben = models.ManyToManyField(Aufgaben, blank=True)
    zusatzinfo = models.OneToOneField(
        Zusatzinfo, verbose_name=_('zusatzinfos'), blank=True, null=True , related_name='zusatzinfo')
```

Some users should be able to add an "Aufgaben"-Object in the django admin page which belongs to an person. But they must not have access to the whole person model. So they should be able to create an "Aufgabe" and select the person to which it belongs. The same with "Zusatzinfo" but both dont have the same relation(onetoone, manytomany) so i dont know if it works the same(if it actually works). I hope i explained it well, if not feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have your relations backwards. If `aufgaben` can only be owned by 1 person that already exists, than `models.ForeignKey` should be set on the `aufgaben`model to `person`. Currently your saying that more than 1 person can have an aufgaben, and an aufgaben can have more than 1 person.

Comment: I asked if i can create an Aufgabe over the admin interface and in the same move define the relating person to the aufgabe. Without having the permission to edit person

Comment: I believe the answer is yes. Is it currently not working for you?